# Ubuntu 16.04 stucks in login page after editing .profile

Tags: xubuntu

i was installing PHPstorm on ubuntu 16.04 that it said to me put bin folder address in PATH variable to access it everywhere. I think i had deleted some texts in it &  after shutting down my login page doesn't work & i'm sure that my password is correct but it shows me a black screen for 1 or 2 seconds and back to login page. How can i solve it ? Thanks

Comment: You need to boot into `recovery mode` then drop to root and `mount file system` in  `rw` mode and access the `.profile` file and fix whatever you deleted.

Comment: You may have put `PATH=/some_dir` instead of `PATH=$PATH:/some_dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the .profile file in Recovery Mode.

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during a reboot, select `Recovery Mode` from the menu, drop to a root shell prompt, then edit the `.profile` file and reboot the system.

If you don't remember your changes to `.profile`, you can copy the system default profile from `/etc/skel/.profile` into your home directory.